# Font awesome 6 icons not showing when using ids

Tags: html, css, font-awesome-6

I'm trying to show an icon on my website but it only works when I remove the id from de a tag.

This is the code:

```css
#link_facebook {
  color: #3b5998;
}
```

```html
<a class="nav-link" id="link_facebook" href="#" role="button" target="_blank">
  <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: can you share website link, because your code working fine in my end. when i add fontawesome link 
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css

Answer (score 0):

Put the color on the `i` element.

```css
i {
    color: #3b5998;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-9usAa10IRO0HhonpyAIVpjrylPvoDwiPUiKdWk5t3PyolY1cOd4DSE0Ga+ri4AuTroPR5aQvXU9xC6qOPnzFeg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<a class="nav-link" id="link_facebook" href="#" role="button" target="_blank">
   <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand about specificity in CSS. You can take a look the document here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

About your style, It can may no apply when the tag `i` or `fa-brands` or `fa-facebook` has `color` style. So for your case you can do like this:

```
#link_facebook i {
  color: #3b5998;
}
```